# Redirecting cout to the new buffer that created with winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'm trying to print to the new screen buffer that i've create with winapi but it's going to the old buffer and doesn't show up on the screen, is it possible, redirecting `cout` to the new screen buffer that created by using winapi?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE stdBuf, nBuf;
    DWORD numberOfChars;

    stdBuf = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    nBuf = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);

    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(nBuf);
    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, nBuf);

    // THIS SHOWING UP ON THE SCREEN
    WriteConsole(nBuf, "SECOND BUFFER", 13, &numberOfChars, NULL);

    // THIS IS GOING TO THE FIRST BUFFER
    std::cout << "SECOND BUFFER with cout" << std::endl;

    Sleep(3000);

    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(stdBuf);
    CloseHandle(nBuf);

    int a = 0;
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. No, it's not necessarily entirely trivial.

The basic problem is fairly simple: there are existing stream buffers to talk to a named file, but (probably) not an existing one to talk to a console. To get this to work, you need one that talks to a console. Here's a fairly simple starting point:

```
class outbuf : public std::streambuf {
    HANDLE h;
public:
    outbuf(HANDLE h) : h(h) {}
protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) override {
        if (c != EOF) {
            DWORD written;
            WriteConsole(h, &c, 1, &written, nullptr);
        }
        return c;
    }

    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(char_type const *s, std::streamsize count) override {
        DWORD written;
        WriteConsole(h, s, count, &written, nullptr);
        return written;
    }
};
```

[Note: this is somewhat incomplete--it does the Console output fine, but if (for example) you copy or assign it, bad things will probably happen--like most stream buffers, you probably shouldn't be able to copy or assign it.]

Once you have a stream buffer that writes its output to a console, connecting it up to `cout` is pretty trivial:

```
console_stream_buffer buff(nBuf);

std::cout.rdbuf(buff);

std:cout << "bleh"; // should go to the console `nBuf`.
```

Here's a quick demo using it:

```
int main() {

    HANDLE h = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    HANDLE original = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Create our stream buffer object
    outbuf ob(h);

    // write to the original buffer
    std::cout << "First console";

    // Set cout to go to the second buffer
    std::cout.rdbuf(&ob);

    // write to it
    std::cout << "Second console";

    // display the second buffer
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(h);

    // show the second buffer for a few seconds:
    Sleep(5000);

    // restore the original buffer
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(original);
}
```

You could, of course, easily write a stream buffer that allocates a console screen buffer for itself, if you wanted to. I left that separate for now, but depending on how you're using things, it may easily make more sense to combine them (and probably include an `activate` member that calls `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer` as well). None of that is really relevant to your original question though, so I'll leave it for now.

Comment: I'm wondering (pretty sure I've seen this) if possibly a simple freopen at the C FILE* level, will do.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: In this case, I don't think that (at least by itself) could work. `freopen` needs a file name, and here we have a Windows HANDLE, but no name. You might be able to use `_open_osfhandle` to get a UNIX-style handle to the console screen buffer, then use `dup2` to redirect stdout to that. `_open_osfhandle` is only documented to work with file handles, not screen buffer handles, but you *can* pass a console screen buffer handle to `WriteFile`, so there's a decent chance it would work. OTOH, I'm not sure that saves much compared to what's above either.

Comment: Uhm, maybe "CONOUT$", or whatever the standard output stream name is in Windows.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That would give you a handle to the same console buffer where it's already writing, not the new one you just created.

Answer (score 0):

@Jerry Coffin Thank you for your answer but it's printing only the characters that is inside between the quotes, it doesn't work with the variables and arrays also `std::endl` doesn't work too.

I think this solution is the right method to deal with the buffers but it's kinda incomplete like you said.

Not working with these: `cout << a; cout << a[5]; cout << endl;`

I wrote something different, it's like double buffering. It's writing to the standard buffer and then displaying it on the second buffer. `rwBuffer()` is sending a particular area of the standard buffer to the second buffer through a `SMALL_RECT`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void rwBuffer(HANDLE h1, HANDLE h2) {
    COORD bufPos = { 0,0 }; // START POINT OF THE R&W BUFFER
    COORD bufSize = { 5, 2 }; // SIZE OF THE R&W BUFFER
    CHAR_INFO bufInfo[10]; // (5 * 2) CHAR INFO FOR THE R&W BUFFER

    SMALL_RECT screenRect = { 0, 0, 4, 1 }; // RESOLUTION FOR READ&WRITE

    // READ FROM "h1" AND WRITE TO THE "h2" THROUGH "screenRect"
    ReadConsoleOutput(h1, bufInfo, bufSize, bufPos, &screenRect);
    WriteConsoleOutput(h2, bufInfo, bufSize, bufPos, &screenRect);
}

int main() {
    HANDLE stdBuffer, secondBuffer;
    int nArray[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    stdBuffer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    secondBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(secondBuffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << nArray[i];
        if (i == 4) std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    rwBuffer(stdBuffer, secondBuffer);
    Sleep(3000);

    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(stdBuffer);
    CloseHandle(secondBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Also it's possible synchronizing the cursor position with the standard cursor position.

```
void syncCursor(HANDLE h2) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bufInfo;
    COORD cursorPos;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &bufInfo);
    cursorPos.X = bufInfo.dwCursorPosition.X;
    cursorPos.Y = bufInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(h2, cursorPos);
}
```

Comment: I'm certain that Jerry Coffin's solution works with arrays. The simple reason is that he didn't change `std::cout` , `std::ostream` or `operator<<`. The `<iostream>` architecture is modular; `ostream` and `operator<<` turn many different types into text. `streambuf` (which Jerry changed) then moves this text to wherever it should go - screen, file, or now the alternate console. You apparently have issues with the first part (turn into text). `std::endl` is a boundary case, though: it means "append \n to the text and send the text to the streambuf now".

Comment: @MSalters: Actually, he's right. I edited the code to add an `xsputn` instead of just `overflow` to my buffer class (which can be a fairly major optimization) but in editing that in, I accidentally replaced the `overflow` that was there instead of having both as intended. I've added the `overflow` back in, which corrects the error.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks i'm gonna search for them, but there is another thing that is still weird, isn't  that `SetStdHandle()` suppose to make this redirection? Why it's still writing to the old buffer?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Now it's working, like you said overflow block fixed it, thank you.